# Smalltalk stdin nextLine for fixed number of lines of input

Tags: io, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I am currently trying to get 3 specific lines of input of the form:

XX.XX (float)
XX (1-3 digit integer)
XX (1-3 digit integer)

Below is the current code I have:

```
inputStringOne := stdin nextLine.
mealCost := inputStringOne.

Transcript show: inputStringOne; cr .

inputStringTwo := stdin nextLine.
tipPercent := inputStringTwo.

Transcript show: inputStringTwo; cr .

inputString := stdin nextLine.
taxPercent := inputString .

mealCost inspect .
tipPercent inspect .
taxPercent inspect .
```

I have been at this for a good 3-4 hours programming, scouring the Internet, etc. I am an uber-beginner teaching myself Smalltalk, so I am trying to see why the nextLine isn't reading the inputs correctly. Below are the sample inputs put into stdin, and the results of the **Transcript show** and **inspect**:

Sample Input on stdin:

```
10.25
17
5
```

Output on stdout:

```
10.25
.25
An instance of String
  contents: [
    [1]: $1
    [2]: $0
    [3]: $.
    [4]: $2
    [5]: $5
  ]
An instance of String
  contents: [
    [1]: $.
    [2]: $2
    [3]: $5
  ]
An instance of String
  contents: [
    [1]: $.
    [2]: $2
    [3]: $5
  ]
10.25
```

When I just do the following code, I see all 3 inputs separated by <10>, which I assume is the carriage-return or linefeed.

```
"just print all contents in stdin"
inputS := stdin contents.
inputS inspect .
```

Sample input (stdin):

```
10.25
17
5
```

Output (stdout):

```
An instance of String
  contents: [
    [1]: $1
    [2]: $0
    [3]: $.
    [4]: $2
    [5]: $5
    [6]: $<10>
    [7]: $1
    [8]: $7
    [9]: $<10>
    [10]: $5
  ]
```

So it seems that for some reason, the first line of the code is the only one gotten by `stdin nextLine .`, but the rest only get the last 3 characters (the decimal point and the 2 digits after the decimal point). I am not sure why this is the case.

I have tried `nextAvailable`, `flush`, `commit`, `stdin close`, and a handful of other methods, all to no avail. One idea I have is to go about this problem is to just get the whole `stdin contents`, split by <10>, then save each "part" to 3 different variables, but I want to learn more about how `stdin nextLine` works and to have a better understanding of how that relates to `stdin contents` as well. Is there no good way to just do `stdin nextLine` 3 times given we know that there are only 3 inputs?

Comment: Kudos for trying to learn Smalltalk, but if you're trying to learn the language, GNU isn't what I'd recommend. Consider trying [Pharo](http://pharo.org/), [VisualWorks](http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com/main/products/visualworks/) or maybe Dolphin or Squeak... learning Smalltalk via command-line seems to me like learning how to produce graphics via punch-cards. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in GNU smalltalk. If you type in the input directly from the keyboard then `stdin nextLine` works just fine. However, if you redirect the input from a file then `stdin nextLine` messes it up.

Significantly, I can't find a single answer in HackerRank that is written in smalltalk so this must be an old problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce this on macOS with GNU Smalltalk 3.2.5:

```
→ gst -f foo.st
12.23
12.23
12
12
7
An instance of String
  contents: [
    [1]: $1
    [2]: $2
    [3]: $.
    [4]: $2
    [5]: $3
  ]
An instance of String
  contents: [
    [1]: $1
    [2]: $2
  ]
An instance of String
  contents: [
    [1]: $7
  ]
```

As you can see every input is echoed back from your `Transcript show:` messages and the output of `inspect` looks correct too. Which OS and version of GNU Smalltalk are you using?

Comment: I'm using GNU Smalltalk 3.2.4. It's through HackerRank, so perhaps there's some type of issue there.

Comment: I believe it may be an issue with the environment setup that doesn't recognize the input bytes properly. I'll have to wait on that to be answered. COBOL had a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

using a very buggy version of smalltalk on another site. The best approach I could find builds on contents.
Note: array in smalltalk starts at 1, not 0.

```
ins := stdin contents substrings '\n'.

loopMax := 3.
ix := 1.
[   line := ins at: ix.
    Transcript show: 'ins at ', ix printString;
        show: ' =', line; cr.
                
    ix := ix + 1.
    b := ix asNumber > loopMax.
] whileFalse: [ b ].
```